# How to do this PG query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following simple relations:

```
class Company
  has_many :users
end

class User
  belongs_to :company
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

The only column that matters is `:name` on `Role`.

I'm trying to make an efficient PostgreSQL query which will show a comma separated list of all `role_names` for each user.

So far I have got it this far, which works great if there's only single role assigned. If I add another role, I get duplicate users. Rather than trying to parse this after, I'm trying to just get it to return a comma separated list in a `role_names` field by using the `string_agg()` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-aggregate.html).

This is my query so far and I'm kind of failing at taking it this final step.

```
User.where(company_id: id)                             
  .joins(:roles)                                       
  .select('distinct users.*, roles.name as role_name')
```

**EDIT**

I can get it working via raw SQL (gross) but rails doesn't know how to understand it when I put it in ActiveRecord format

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT users.*, string_agg("roles"."name", \',\') as roles FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "users"."company_id" = 1 GROUP BY users.id')

User.where(company_id: id)
  .joins(:roles)
  .select('users.*, string_agg("roles"."name" \',\')')
  .group('users.id')
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you just want a list of all roles a user has, use `User#roles`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you want to do:

```
User.roles.map(&:name).join(',')
```

(In my opionion SQL is a better choice when working with databases but when you are on rails you should probably do as much as possible with Active Record. Be aware of performance issues!)